# How do you plot interaction effects in SAS?

Tags: regression, sas, interaction

I want to plot interaction between two variables in SAS. One is continuous and the other is binary.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is some information that may be of interest to you](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/hetreg.htm).  (UCLA's Stat Computing site is wonderful).

Comment: The code there gives the data output...but how did they generate the scatterplots?

Comment: I'm running SAS 9.2.  When ODS graphics are turned on, the plots are automatically generated when you run proc glm.  To specify specific plots, see [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect044.htm).

Comment: As with what Mike said, turn on ODS, check your documentations, and look for a plots=ALL option somewhere in whatever procedure you're running.